# Is there a CPAN module to extract the current level of content from an email

Tags: perl, cpan, text-extraction

I'm looking for a module to do a best-effort attempt to extract the immediate level of content (ie discarding any quoted content and the signature block) from the plain text component of an email.

We've already got some code that has a shot at it, so if there is no existing module that does it, ideas for a name for a new module would also be appreciated (`Text::ExtractImmediateLevelOfContentFromEmail` seems a bit unwieldy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there's no such module because that's very task oriented and there's a huge variety of message formatting styles. The minimal implementation is something you can do with a few lines of code:

```
use Email::MIME;
my $email = Email::MIME->new($message);
my $body;
$email->walk_parts(sub {
    my ($part) = @_;
    return unless $part->content_type =~ m[text/plain];
    $body .= $part->body;
});

# strip quoted lines and attribution line
$body =~ s/^.+ wrote:\n(?=\n* ?>)//m;
$body =~ s/^ ?>.*\n//gm;

# strip signature
$body =~ s/-- \R.+//;
```

Of course you may want to add other heuristic rules to remove attribution lines written in other languages, as well as removing Outlook-style quoted text.
I'd suggest some heuristics to avoid quoted text stripping if the message is recognized to use interleaved-style quoting. That's because interleaved replies may loose some meaning if you strip quoted text.

If you want to factor that out to a module, I'd call it `Email::ExtractBody` or `Email::ExtractText`. I'd stress in the POD that the module has a heuristic and best-effort approach.